# specify multiple integers with Javascript .includes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get an alert to go off only if all of the integers in the single condition are the same as the integers in a list playerNumbers. The first set (1 && 2 && 3) works, but anything above this (4 && 5 && 6) does not work, because 4 and beyond include 1 , 2 and 3, making the first condition true. What could I do to make it so only if the specific values are specified then the condition is met?

```
     function determinePlayerWin() {
   if (playerNumbers.includes(1 && 2 && 3)) {
     alert('player win!');
   }
    else if (playerNumbers.includes(4 && 5 && 6)) {
     alert('player win!');
   }
   else if (playerNumbers.includes(7 && 8 && 9)) {
     alert('player win!');
   }
   else if (playerNumbers.includes(1 && 4 && 7)) {
     alert('player win!');
   }
    else if (playerNumbers.includes(2 && 5 && 8)) {
     alert('player win!');
   }
   else if (playerNumbers.includes(3 && 6 && 9)) {
     alert('player win!');
   }
   else if (playerNumbers.includes(1 && 5 && 9)) {
     alert('player win!');
   }
    else if (playerNumbers.includes(3 && 5 && 7)) {
     alert('player win!');
   }

 }
```

Comment: Please verify that you are using any API correctly. In this case Array.includes(). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes. Also note that x && y && z will evaluate to z if all values are truthy.

Comment: `x && y && z` is a boolean. U r checking if your array includes a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

A chain of `&&`s as a single expression where every condition is truthy will evaluate to the last value, eg

```
.includes(1 && 2 && 3)
```

is the same as

```
.includes(3)
```

Instead, use an array and check that `every` element of the array is included in `playerNumbers`:

```
if ([1, 2, 3].every(num => playerNumbers.includes(num))) {
  // win
}
```

You could also make an array of each win-array to make the code more DRY, eg:

```
const winArrs = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  // ...
];
if (winArrs.some(winArr => (
  winArr.every(num => playerNumbers.includes(num)))
)) {
  // win
}
```